# Devise sign out path is taking me to Users#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Does anyone have any insight to this, its as the title says. Ive not altered to devise code or anything like that but all of a sudden i cant sign out anymore. it just takes me to Users/show

```
<%= link_to "delete",  :controller => "devise/sessions", :action => "destroy" %>

<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete  %></li>
```

routes:

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: {
 registrations: 'users/registrations',
 omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"
```

}

When clicked it takes me to `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out` this path but its actually the User#show page

This is from rails routes:

```
destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                 devise/sessions#destroy
```

The only way to sign out is by closing the browser to delete the cookie then i can sign back in

Comment: Sorry both are doing it, I just created the extra link to test a different syntax

Comment: @NMPennypacker Ok ive just removed all my js code as a test and its working so it must be my dodgy code! ill look into it. Thanks. (What should i do about marking it anwsered)

Comment: I've converted my comment to an answer. Feel free to accept if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your links are set up correctly. I'd be willing to be that you have some Javascript hiding somewhere that's targeting that link (perhaps there is a class on it that is used in an `on('click')` somewhere).

If that's the case, try adding `preventDefault()` to that Javascript so that the default link click behavior is ignored.

Comment: This is correct, but i will say the js that i deleted to fix it had nothing to do with that link, it must have deeply ingrained into it somehow.